# How to make objects collide with tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am very new to programming and I'm trying to make a simple animation where I append 10 balls of random size, random color and random speed to the canvas. Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

WIDTH = 900
HEIGHT = 700

tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT)
tk.title("Drawing")
canvas.pack()

COLORS = ["white", "black", "red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange", "gray"]
balls = []

class Ball:

    def __init__(self, color, size):
        self.shape = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, size, size, fill = color)
        self.xspeed = random.randrange(-11, 11)
        self.yspeed = random.randrange(-11, 11)

    def move(self):
        canvas.move(self.shape, self.xspeed, self.yspeed)
        pos = canvas.coords(self.shape)
        if pos[3] >= HEIGHT or pos[1] <= 0:
            self.yspeed = -self.yspeed
        if pos[2] >= WIDTH or pos[0] <= 0:
            self.xspeed = -self.xspeed

for i in range(10):
    size = random.randrange(20, 150)
    color = random.choice(COLORS)
    balls.append(Ball(color, size))

while True:
    for ball in balls:
        ball.move()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)

tk.mainloop()
```

The problem is that balls are able to overlap each other i. e. when balls touch each other, nothing happens. I want the balls to bounce off of each other when they touch. I have spent several hours searching for answer and trying different things but nothing seems to help. Could you guys help me?